# How to save a game so all profiles can load it?

Tags: xbox-360, lego-star-wars

My sons have been playing Lego Star Wars TCS.  We started the game under my profile and that's where the game is saved.  But in order to load it, it must be loaded from the controller that is signed in as me.

Is there a way to set it up so that my sons' profiles could load the game too?

Comment: I believe I once found a method online, that involves 2 joypads and the 2 profiles logged in, then disconnecting one and returning to dashboard... I don't rembember well and I haven't tested it anyway.

Comment: My advice is to have one of your sons decide who will host a multiplayer game between the two of them so you wont have to load your profile each time as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there's not. Save games are stored separately for different profiles and there's no way to migrate them to another profile.

Answer (score 4):

This is very easy to do, you need just 5 minutes:

- Put your save game file on a USB drive
- Use a tool like Modio or Horizon to open the file
- Change the player ID of the game (you can find many tutorial in YouTube)
- Save the file on USB "rehash and resign using the tool"
- Put on the XBox and you can use the other account!